# Logistic regression: controlling variables not significant, what should I conclude/further test?

Tags: regression, logistic

I ran annual logisitic regression on time-series datas. The most important independant variable have coefficient that are significant in a lot of years, that's a relief. But the "controlling variables", have non-significant coefficients. I'm far from an expert in stats.

My sample is very small compared to the litterature that made that test, because I'm analysing a sub-industry that has very few companies in it. But I can't change my sample.

In the literature, the authors that made this precise analysis on bigger samples found significant coefficients to controlling variables too, fact they use to state that: "the effect of the main variable is therefore a separate effect than the ones of controlling variables".

As I can't say that, should I test the correlation between these variables and the main one, and eliminate some of them that present a very high correlation with it every year, stating that these are redundant variables ? If so, which level is considered high ? 0.75, 0.8 ?

I'm planning to say:

- Main variable is significant, but not controlling variable
- There are two potential reasons:
  1) My yearly samples are too small
  2) The effect of the main variable is the same as the effect of some of these controlling variables
- To try to rule out 2), I tested correlation and found that bla bla bla (if low correlations, probably the samples are just too small, if high, I eliminate some variables and re-run regressions)

### ------------------------------------------------------------

Following Peter's answer (thank you !), I think I should add some details about what I'm testing my study:

***Is the propensity to distribute dividends (1 or 0) dependant of the firm's life-cycle stage (using a ratio) ?***

Controlling for profitability, asset growth rate, size (market cap.), and lagged dividends (1 or 0).

In every year, the coefficient for lagged dividend is highly significant. And for some of the years (sufficiently for my student thesis), the coefficient of firm's life-cycle stage is significant. The signs of all the other controlling variables are as predicted (most of the time), but always far from significant. I'm hoping that doesn't make my model irrelevant. My pseudo-R square are pretty high. (By the way, does this pseudo-R take in account the variables that are non-significant, or is it the value of the model including only variables that have a significant coefficient ?)

Comment: Per your request, I'm closing (not deleting) this thread to signal it is *pending a decision on your part* wrt. future update or request for clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons to include control variables even if they are not significant. E.g.

1) Including them may affect the parameter on the main independent variable (to my mind, this is the true meaning of a "control" variable).

2) Finding a small effect may be important, if others have found a large one.  The idea that the null hypothesis always has to be "something" = 0 is not right. Maybe you want to test if the covariates are the same as in some other work?

3) They may be so standard in the field that not including them would lead to lots of skepticism about the model.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer ! I understand your first point and third point, but not very well the second one. I believe that means that my suggestion of correlation is not the right test to do: that's covariance that I should calculate, and if I find that some variable have a very high covariance with the main independent variable for a few years, I might try to re-run the regressions while eliminating this variable.

Comment: I have edited my original question to explain briefly my study and my results